# In the Valdemar series by Mercedes Lackey, what happens to a Companion when the Herald dies of ''natural causes''?

Tags: mercedes-lackey, valdemar

I recently read a short story in ''[Changing the World: All-New Tales of Valdemar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6307037-changing-the-world)'', the first one (actually written by Lackey, and titled "Changing the World").

In this short story there is mention of a Herald who dies of sickness, but it doesn't mention what happens to the Companion.

So my question: What happens to a Companion when a Herald dies of natural causes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the Herald that died is the King's Own or Queen's Own, then the Companion will choose another Herald. This is because the position of King's/Queen's Own is so important that it needs to be filled. Also, the position of King's/Queen's Own *Companion* is so important, that they do not have the option of wallowing in depression or withering away and dying. They have a duty to bond again to another Herald who will then become the King's/Queens Own Herald.

It is mentioned in a number of books that the profession of being a Herald is dangerous, so Heralds do not tend to die of natural causes.

> "Heralds didn’t tend to grow old. Even in times of peace, they lived lives that lowered the odds of them dying in bed to slightly less than negligible." *Moving Targets and Other Tales of Valdemar*

I would imagine that if/when a Herald does die of natural causes, their Companion would soon follow them into death... The same as they do when Heralds die unnatural deaths.

> "She'd die, lad; Companions very seldom outlive their Chosen. And she Chose you. If you die, she dies; she'd probably pine herself to death, and she does not deserve that." *Magic's Pawn*

Answer (score 1):

From wikipedia, its written that

> Heralds are held to an extraordinarily high moral standard, however. If a Herald or Herald-Trainee does not abide by this moral standard, they will be hounded by their Companion until they do abide by it and one who does unforgivable acts, will generally be repudiated by their Companion. This will usually be followed up by the Companion's suicide in some manner or another.
>
> The result for the repudiated Herald or Herald-Trainee is generally a wound so deep that it may mar the soul, though that is not assured, but it will also quite commonly leave the victim catatonic as a result, blankly nonresponsive. Those who are responsive, are typically insane to the point that they are unable to use any Gifts that they might possess. However, repudiation does not necessarily mean that one is relieved of their Herald status, as when Tylendel was repudiated, the Death Bell tolled for him, indicating that he was accepted by the Companions as a full Herald and should be buried with Herald's honors. One can assume that Tylendel was given this distinction because his repudiation and the terrible act perpetrated causing it were caused by severe psychological trauma.

also

> The foremost and notable Reincarnations are embodied by the Companions, who were initially born from pure Light in "the Companion's Field Grove". The soul reincarnated within each Companion is always from a deceased Heral